# I m using fluent wait but i dont know why i m getting error on function

Tags: selenium

I want to use fluent wait in my code but I am getting error on `Function(Function<Boolean> f = new Function<Boolean>())` line.

```
FluentWait<WebElement> wait = new FluentWait<WebElement>(verificationtxt);

wait.withTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

wait.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

Function<Boolean> f = new Function<Boolean>()
        {
    public Boolean apply(WebElement verificationtxt)
    {
        if(verificationtxt.getText().length()>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
        };
wait.until(f);
```

Comment: And which error do you get?

Comment: Looks like there is a space needed before the string 'txt'.

Comment: hi olyv thanks for looking into this. i am getting the red line below the function keyword. and when i mouse hover on it. it is giving me suggestions to resolve that error and i have tried that suggestions  also.

Answer (score 0):

This line should be:

```java
Function<WebElement, Boolean> f = new Function<WebElement, Boolean>()
```

Full source code:

package test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;

import com.google.common.base.Function;

public class FluentWaitTest {

```
public void fluentWaitDemo() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    WebElement verificationtxt = driver.findElement(By.name("verificationtxt"));

    FluentWait<WebElement> wait = new FluentWait<WebElement>(verificationtxt);

    wait.withTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    wait.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    Function<WebElement, Boolean> f = new Function<WebElement, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebElement verificationtxt) {
            if (verificationtxt.getText().length() > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    wait.until(f);
}
```

}

Comment: hi Sergii Pozharov , Thanks your reply i have used the same thing but it still giving me error on function. so for this i have to import some namespaces.cud u provide me sample code for FluentWait.my mailid is andyjain1990@gmail.com thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Anant Jain, I've updated answer with full source code.
What IDE are you using? In Eclipse you can mouse over the error and it will propose you quick fixes, including importing required packages.
Can you provide the exact error that you have?

Comment: Hey Hi Sergii, thanks for your kind reply i got d solution i didn't add the import com.google.common.base.Function;due to this it was giving me error.once again thank you